# Search inside txt file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

On **www.example.com/page_a/** is it possible to run a javascript code that searches for the text "hello" inside the file located at **www.example.com/page_b/my_file.txt** ?

Is this possible with javascript/jquery/ any other javascript framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and it is simplest with jquery.

You need to "get" contents of the text file like this:

```
$.get("www.example.com/page_b/my_file.txt", function(contents){
   //contents variable now contains the contents of the textfile as string

   //check if file contains the word Hello
   var hasString = contents.includes("Hello");

   //outputs true if contained, else false
   console.log(hasString);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using jquery $.get()

```
$.get("text file path",function(textString) {
    // handle the returned string ..
},"text/plain")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using indexOf() to search a string in a text file using JavaScript. Here is the code

```
$.get("www.example.com/page_b/my_file.txt", function(contents){
   var str = "Hello";
   if(contents.indexOf(str) != -1){
       console.log(str + " found");
   }
})
```